# Using StreamBuilder for the same stream and impact of it on number of reads from firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following getter function to fetch user profile data from firestore.

```
  Stream<UserProfile> get userProfile {
    FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    try {
      return _auth.currentUser == null
          ? null
          : _firestore
              .collection('users')
              .doc(_auth.currentUser.uid)
              .snapshots()
              .map(
                (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) => UserProfile(
                  uid: documentSnapshot.data()['uid'],
                  email: documentSnapshot.data()['email'],
                ),
              );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

To my understanding, this getter will later be used with a StreamBuilder. And calling this getter will increase my number of reads by 1 in firebase firestore, and the number of reads will only be increased when this specific user data changes (when updated).

But how does the number of reads change if I call this getter in 2 different flutter files/widgets? Since I call it at 2 different places, will that mean that number of reads is increased by 1 for each call that is made from each unique file? Or, does it overall cost 1 read for me because I use the same getter even if I call it at different places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you invoke this code:

```
          _firestore
              .collection('users')
              .doc(_auth.currentUser.uid)
              .snapshots()
```

It is going to cost at least 1 read, plus more reads every time the document changes.  It doesn't matter if the code is in a getter function, or whatever way you choose to make this query, it's going to cost the same.

If you want all of your code to share a single stream, then you should execute query only once, store the Stream, and provide that stream independently.